# What is a non-deprecated way to do `new.classobj(name, (base_class,), my_dict)`

Tags: python, saucelabs

I found in saucelabs `example.py` file the following code snippet using the `import new` module.

```
import new
# .. snip ..
def on_platforms(platforms):
    def decorator(base_class):
        module = sys.modules[base_class.__module__].__dict__
        for i, platform in enumerate(platforms):
            d = dict(base_class.__dict__)
            d['desired_capabilities'] = platform
            name = "%s_%s" % (base_class.__name__, i + 1)
            module[name] = new.classobj(name, (base_class,), d)
    return decorator
```

However reading the `help(new)` shows that that module is deprecated. What is a non-depreciated way to do `new.classobj(name, (base_class,), d)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `type` keyword is a class. You can perform the above using

```
module[name] = type(name, (base_class,), d)
```

This will return a class of name `name` with the tuple parameters of the base class `base_class`, initializing the member objects with the `dict` `d`.